# Content are not getting displayed. Facing issues in troubleshooting the my project on social media website for college

Tags: php, html, ajax

Edit: Issue has been resolved. The culprit was a misplaced single quote :P 
The first image where content is getting displayed:
[image: The first image where content is getting displayed]

The second image is where no content is getting displayed
[image: The second image is where no content is getting displayed]

I have asked this question already a few days ago and my problem got solved there, but suddenly the problem occurred again and I can't seem to find the solution for it. What i'm trying to do is load the posts that will exceed 10 posts while scrolling but no posts are getting displayed when I'm adding Ajax.
Here is the code:

```
     index.php code:    
    <?php
    include("includes/header.php");
    include("includes/classes/User.php");
include("includes/classes/Post.php");
if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
    $post=new Post($con,$userLoggedIn);
    $post->submitPost($_POST['post_text'],'none');
}
?>
<div class="user_details column">
    <a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>" > <img src="<?php echo $user['profile_pic']; ?>"></a>
    <div class="user_details_left_right">
    <a href="<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>">
    <?php
    echo $user['first_name'] . " " . $user['last_name'];
    ?>
    </a>
    <br>
    <?php
    echo "My Posts: " . $user['num_post'] . "<br>";
    echo "Likes: " . $user['num_likes'];
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main_column column">
    <form class="post_form" action="index.php" method="POST">
        <textarea name="post_text" id="post_text" placeholder="Write something here..."></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="post" id="post_button" value="Post">
        <hr>
    </form>
    <!--<?php
    $post=new Post($con,$userLoggedIn);
    $post->loadPostsFriends();
    ?>-->
    <div class="posts_area"></div>
    <img id="loading" src="assets/images/icons/loading.gif">
</div>
<script>
    var userLoggedIn = '<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>';
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#loading').show();
        //ajax request for loading 1st posts
        $.ajax({
           url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
           cache:false,
           success: function(data)
            {
                $("#loading").hide();
                $('.posts_area').html(data);
            }
        });
        $(window).scroll(function()
        {
         var height=$('.posts_area').height(); //div containing posts
         var scroll_top=$(this).scrollTop();
         var page=$('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').val();
         var noMorePosts=$('posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').val();
         if((document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) && noMorePosts == 'false')
             {
                $('#loading').show();
                alert("hello");
                var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
                url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
                cache:false,
                success: function(response)
                {
                 $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').remove(); //removes current next page
                 $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').remove();
                 $('#loading').hide();
                 $('.posts_area').append(response);
                }
              });
             } //If end
            return false;
        }); //ending of $(window).scroll(function()
    });
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Post.php code:   
<?php
class Post 
{
    private $user_obj;
    private $con;
    public function __construct($con,$user)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
        $this->user_obj = new User($con,$user);
    }
    //$user_obj=new User($con,$userLoggedIn)
    public function submitPost($body,$user_to)
    {
        $body=strip_tags($body); //To remove any HTML tag
        $body=mysqli_escape_string($this->con, $body);
        $check_empty=preg_replace('/\s+/','',$body); //To delete spaces
        if($check_empty != "")
        {
            //Date and time
            $date_added=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            //get user name
            $added_by=$this->user_obj->getUsername();
            //If user is watching his/her own profile, user_to is none
            if($user_to == $added_by)
            {
                $user_to = "none";
            }
            //Insert post
            $query = mysqli_query($this->con,"INSERT INTO posts VALUES('','$body','$added_by','$user_to','$date_added','no','no','0')");
            $returned_id=mysqli_insert_id($this->con);
            //Insert noti
            //Update posts count
            $num_posts=$this->user_obj->getNumPosts();
            $num_posts++;
            $update_query=mysqli_query($this->con,"UPDATE users SET num_post='$num_posts' WHERE username='$added_by'");
        }
    }
    public function loadPostsFriends($data,$limit)
    {
        $page=$data['page'];
        $userLoggedIn=$this->user_obj->getUsername();
        if($page == 1)
            $start = 0;
        else
            $start = ($page-1) * $limit;   
        $str=""; //Str to return
        $data_query=mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE deleted='no' ORDER BY id DESC");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($data_query) > 0)
        {
        $num_iterations = 0; //number of result checking
        $count=1;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data_query))
        {
            $id=$row['id'];
            $body=$row['body'];
            $data[] = $id;
            $data[] = $body;
            $added_by=$row['added_by'];
            $date_time=$row['date_added'];
            //prepare user_to string to include it even if not posted to an user
            if($row['user_to'] == "none")
            {
                $user_to="";
            }
            else
            {
               $user_to_obj=new User($con,$row['user_to']);
               $user_to_name=$user_to_obj->getFirstAndLastName();
               $user_to="wrote to <a href'" . $row['user_to'] . "'>" . $user_to_name . "</a>";
            }
            //check if userwho posted has their account closed
            $added_by_obj=new User($this->con,$added_by);
            if($added_by_obj->isClosed())
            {
                continue;
            }
            if($num_iterations++ < $start)
                continue;
            //once 10 posts loaded just break
            if($count > $limit)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $count++;    
            }
            $user_details_query=mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT first_name,last_name,profile_pic FROM users WHERE username='$added_by'");
            $user_row=mysqli_fetch_array($user_details_query);
            $first_name=$user_row['first_name'];
            $last_name=$user_row['last_name'];
            $profile_pic=$user_row['profile_pic'];
            //Datetime
            $date_time_now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $start_date=new DateTime($date_time); //Post date & time
            $end_date=new DateTime($date_time_now); //Current time
            $interval=$start_date->diff($end_date); //Difference between above 2 dates
            if($interval->y >= 1)
            {
                if($interval==1)
                    $time_message=$interval->y . "year ago"; //1 year ago
                else
                    $time_message=$interval->y . "year ago"; //More than 1 year ago
            }
            else if($interval-> m >= 1)
            {
                if($interval->d == 0)
                {
                    $days=" ago";
                }
                else if($interval-> d == 1)
                {
                    $days=$interval->d . " day ago";
                }
                else
                {
                    $days=$interval->d . " days ago";
                }
                if($interval->m == 1)
                {
                    $time_message=$interval->m . " month" . $days;
                }
                else
                {
                    $time_message=$interval->m . " months" . $days;
                } 
            }
            else if($interval->d >= 1)
            {
                 if($interval-> d == 1)
                {
                    $time_message="Yesterday";
                }
                else
                {
                    $time_message=$interval->d . " days ago";
                }
            }
            else if($interval->h >=1)
            {
                 if($interval-> h == 1)
                {
                    $time_message=$interval->h . " hour ago";
                }
                else
                {
                    $time_message=$interval->h . " hours ago";
                }
            }
            else if($interval->i >=1)
            {
                 if($interval-> i == 1)
                {
                    $time_message=$interval->i . " minute ago";
                }
                else
                {
                    $time_message=$interval->i . " minutes ago";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                 if($interval-> s < 30)
                {
                    $time_message="Just Now!";
                }
                else
                {
                    $time_message=$interval->s . " seconds ago";
                }
            }
            $str .= "<div class='status_post'>
                      <div class='post_profile_pic'>
                       <img src='$profile_pic' width='50'>
                      </div>
                      <div class='posted_by' style='color:#BDBDBD;'>
                       <a href='$added_by'> $first_name $last_name </a> $user_to &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; $time_message
                      </div>
                      <div id='post_body'>$body<br></div>
                     </div><hr>";
        }
            if($count > $limit)
                $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='nextPage' value='" . ($page+1) . "'><input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='false'>";
            else
                $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='true'><p style='text-align:center;'>No more posts!</p>";
        }
        echo $str;
    }
}
?>

user.php code:     
<?php
class User 
{
    private $user;
    private $con;
    public function __construct($con,$user)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
        $user_details_query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
        $this->user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details_query);
    }
    //$user_obj=new User($con,$userLoggedIn)
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->user['username'];
    }
    public function getNumPosts()
    {
        $username=$this->user['username'];
        $query=mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT num_post FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        return $row['num_post'];
    }
    public function getFirstAndLastName()
    {
        $username=$this->user['username'];
        $query=mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        return $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'];
    }
    public function isClosed()
    {
        $username=$this->user['username'];
        $query=mysqli_query($this->con,"SELECT user_closed FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        if($row['user_closed']=='yes')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public function isFriend($username_to_check)
    {
        $usernameComma="," . $username_to_check . ",";
        if((strstr($this->user['friend_array'],$usernameComma)) || $username_to_check==$this->user['username'])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>

ajaxloadpost.php code:    
<?php
include("../../config/config.php");
include("../classes/User.php");
include("../classes/Post.php");
$limit=10; //Limit post to 10 each time
$posts=new Post($con,$_REQUEST['userLoggedIn']);
$posts->loadPostsFriends($_REQUEST,$limit);
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify **what exactly** is not working with all that code and what you've tried to debug the problem?

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply! As you can see in the first pic, the posts are getting displayed. As for the 2nd post, I implemented the ajax code to show loading of the post that will exceed 10 posts while scrolling. But the content from DB is just not visible anymore and there is simply no error.

Comment: And what is your question about that? Have you debugged whether the AJAX call is done properly, the server returns the proper data, the JS code is able to inject this data properly,....?

Comment: Found the error. Problem was a misplaced single quote xD Thanks for your help anyway.